# how to resample without skipping nan values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying get the 10 days aggregate of my data which has NaN values. The sum of 10  days should return a nan values if there is a NaN value in the 10 day duration.

When I apply the below code, pandas is considering NaN as Zero and returning the sum of remaining days.

```
dateRange = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=len(data), freq='D')
# Creating a data frame so that the timeseries can handle numpy array.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
base_Series = pd.DataFrame(list(df.values), index=dateRange)
# Converting to aggregated series
agg_series = base_Series.resample('10D', how='sum')
agg_data = agg_series.values
```

**Sample Data:**

```
2011-06-01  46.520536
2011-06-02   8.988311
2011-06-03   0.133823
2011-06-04   0.274521
2011-06-05   1.283360
2011-06-06   2.556313
2011-06-07   0.027461
2011-06-08   0.001584
2011-06-09   0.079193
2011-06-10   2.389549
2011-06-11        NaN
2011-06-12   0.195844
2011-06-13   0.058720
2011-06-14   6.570925
2011-06-15   0.015107
2011-06-16   0.031066
2011-06-17   0.073008
2011-06-18   0.072198
2011-06-19   0.044534
2011-06-20   0.240080
```

**Output:**

```
2011-06-01  62.254651
2011-06-11   7.301481
```

Answer (score 5):

This uses numpy sum which will return nan if nan is present in the sum

```
In [35]: s = Series(randn(100),index=date_range('20130101',periods=100))

In [36]: s.iloc[11] = np.nan

In [37]: s.resample('10D',how=lambda x: x.values.sum())
Out[37]: 
2013-01-01    6.910729
2013-01-11         NaN
2013-01-21   -1.592541
2013-01-31   -2.013012
2013-02-10    1.129273
2013-02-20   -2.054807
2013-03-02    4.669622
2013-03-12    3.489225
2013-03-22    0.390786
2013-04-01   -0.005655
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Question: Why am I getting 3 values when I do resampling with the suggested data? I get `2011-06-01`, `2011-06-11` and `2011-06-21`. Pandas 0.12 and the master. Where did it got the `2011-06-21` date?

Comment: I think if you do closed='left' if wont include the extra data point (right is the default)

Comment: Nope, that's the first thing I tried. It looks like a bug. Because even if I change the last timestamp to `2011-06-19 23:59:59` it still gives me the third value for `2011-06-21`.

Comment: yep a bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4076 ; want to do do a PR? haven't had time to look at this

Comment: PR? Sorry :( Not familiar with terminology :) Pull Request? Add a comment to the issue?

Comment: yep - pull request - to fix the issue! see http://pandas.pydata.org/developers.html

Comment: Not sure I'm competent enough but I'll try :)

Comment: Huh it's super complicated :D First, it's partially produced by a hack to fix another bugs (`_adjust_bin_edges` metod). And second, some unit-tests rely on the thing that it will produce an extra bin :-/ So if I want to keep it backward compatible it can be avoided just in some really really special cases. I can give you a diff that makes the unit-tests pass and works in this case and also in the case of the bug report but without duplicated indexes. But the diff is super, extra ugly and I would never commit it :)

Comment: haha....super complicated hacking is my specialty.....pls put up (can just be a reference to a branch of yours is fine...) for reference....I'll take a look but not for a bit...thanks for the effort

Comment: Here it is... [bin_fixer.diff](https://gist.github.com/alefnula/6393351) But as I said it's just a special case so I don't think it's worth the effort :-/ There must be a more general solution, but I'm not that familiar with the codebase... Yet :)

Comment: The `how` argument of `Series.resample` was [removed in Pandas 1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

Instead, you can use `s.resample('10D').aggregate(lambda x: x.values.sum())`.

Comment: Another thing that tripped me up: in this case, you can't replace `x.values.sum()` with `np.sum(x)`, because x is a Pandas series and Pandas apparently translates Numpy functions into its own, which skip NaNs by default.

You can, however, use `x.sum(skipna=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

to filter out those days which have any NaNs, I propose that you do

```
noNaN_days_only = s.groupby(lambda x: x.date).filter(lambda x: ~x.isnull().any()
```

where `s` is a `DataFrame`

Comment: How is this different from s.dropna()? :) The data is already date sampled.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply an agg function:

```
agg_series = base_Series.resample('10D').agg(lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x).all() else np.sum(x) )
```